# How to unit test an array as a prop using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How would you match mock props to the wrapper component props, im a bit confused. I know how to do it in enzyme jest. But not sure how to do it with react-testing-library.

I'm trying it match props.comments to the wrapper:

```
const commentList = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
```

What should i be checking for ? I want to match the prop comments to the comments in the render/wrapper ?

Should i test it like this

```
 const commentList = render(<CommentList comments={props.comments}/>);
 expect(commentList).toHaveLength(2)
```

What would be the right approach to test mock items in an array.

**CommentList.test.tsx**

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import React, { Ref } from "react";
import CommentList from "./CommentList";
import { render, getByText, queryByText, getAllByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";

const props = {
    user: {},
    postId: null,
    userId: null,
    currentUser: {},
    ref: {
        current: undefined,
    },
    comments: [
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 520,
            postId: 28,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 9,
        },
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 519,
            postId: 27,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 10,
        },
    ],
    deleteComment: jest.fn(),
};
describe("Should render <CommentList/>", () => {
    it("should render <CommentList/>", () => {
        const commentList = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        expect(commentList).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should render first comment", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-list-div");
        expect(commentList.firstChild).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should render second child", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-list-div");
        expect(commentList.lastChild).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should check comments", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        const commentList = getByTestId("comment-list-div");
        expect(commentList).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

**CommentList.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, Ref } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import OurSecondaryButton from "../../../common/OurSecondaryButton";
import CommentListContainer from "../commentListContainer/commentListContainer";

function CommentList(props: any, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<Number>(2);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const the_comments = props.comments.length;
    const inc = showMore as any;
    const min = Math.min(2, the_comments - inc);
    const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inc + 2 && inc <= the_comments) {
            setShowMore(inc + 2);
            setShowLessFlag(true);
        } else {
            setShowMore(the_comments);
        }
    };
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const showLessComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(2);
        setShowLessFlag(false);
    };
    const isBold = (comment) => {
        return comment.userId === props.userId ? 800 : 400;
    };
    // show comments by recent, and have the latest comment at the bottom, with the previous one just before it.
    const filterComments = props.comments
        .slice(0)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt) as any;
            const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt) as any;
            return date2 - date1;
        })
        .slice(0, inc)
        .reverse();

    const showMoreComments = () => {
        return filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ));
    };
    console.log(ref);
    return (
        <Grid data-testid="comment-list-div">
            <Fragment>
                <div style={{ margin: "30px 0px" }}>
                    {props.comments.length > 2 ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    {min !== 0 ? (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            View {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? min : 0} More Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    ) : (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            Show Less Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    )}
                                </Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                    Show Less Comments
                                </OurSecondaryButton>
                            )}
                        </Fragment>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
            {showLessFlag === true ? (
                // will show most recent comments below
                showMoreComments()
            ) : (
                <Fragment>
                    {/* filter based on first comment  */}
                    {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default React.forwardRef(CommentList) as React.RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, any>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test against visual elements rendered in the comments list. If your component renders comment bodies, you could do :

```
const rtl = render(<CommentList comments={props.comments}/>);

// test that both comments bodies are present in DOM
expect(rtl.getByText('firstCommentBody').toBeTruthy();
expect(rtl.getByText('secondCommentBody').toBeTruthy();

// or testing number of individual comment, assuming they are in li.comment, wrapped in a div with data-testid=comment-wrapper
expect(rtl.getByTestId('comment-wrapper').querySelectorAll('li.comment').length).toEqual(2);
```

React-testing-library promotes to test like a real user would : check printed strings, number of elements, labels, placeholders, roles...

Just ask yourself : what do I expect to see on the screen ? Write your tests as you answer this question.

Comment: thank you for the explanation , going to try this out.

Comment: the last line of code seems to be out of syntax, is it possible for you to refactor it.

Comment: indeed, fixed (querySelectorAll instead of querySelector)

Comment: Thanks got the tests passing now :) really appreciate this.